# MapDB file backup

Tags: java, database, file, mapdb

I'm using a file-backed MapDB which I create like this:

```
File dbFile = new File("db");
DBMaker.newFileDB(dbFile)
    .closeOnJvmShutdown()
    .make();
```

I noticed that there are 3 files being created:

1. db
2. db.p
3. db.t

I need a way store and retrieve a DB remotely. I need to use a single file (store a file / retrieve a file). Do I need all three files? I found that trying to recreate a DB from just the "main" file (db) throws an exception. Is there a way (some config option or something) I can tell MapDB to use only one file?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New MapDB 2 uses single file storage, so there is no .p file.

.t file is transaction log and should be deleted if db is closed correctly.

Comment: It does seem to work - however, the file size is much bigger. A relatively empty DB gave me about 38KB in version 1, but the same DB in version 2 is 2MB! Do you know if there's something to do? I tried playing the the values of allocateStartSize / allocateIncrement, but it didn't help... :(